# How to make a function copies of itself with just changing some things and changing it?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to change the small things of a function every 3 seconds.

```
`    function increase(){
     let numbers = 1;
     document.getElementById("videoplayer").src=document.querySelectorAll('img')[numbers].src;
     var interval = document.getElementById("timers").value*1000;
     setTimeout(increaser, 3000);
 }
 function increaser(){
     
document.getElementById("videoplayer").src=document.querySelectorAll('img')[2].src;
 }`
```

I need to change the numbers variable(let) every 3 seconds so that it can change to the next image. I need the numbers to increase up by 1 every 3 seconds instead of writing seperate functions as in the example.

I tried changing that with the  and changing that number and matching that number to the number needed and that did not work. Is there a way using js in order to increase that number every 3 seconds?

Comment: create a global var and increment it

Comment: I tried that and did not work. Please leave your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a var and use it using setInterval.

In the button, at a code to start a interval on the increase function.

In the increase function add "var + 1";

Then you can add some code so it doesn't throw a lot of errors